# Correctly find probability of binominal probability when $n$ and $p$ are sufficiently large

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Let $X\sim Bin(30, 0.60)$ and $f(x)=x^2$

> (A) Calculate the probablitiy P(X-1=30) and P(29>=X).

My solution:

Since $np=30*0.60=18>10$ and $n(1-p)=30(0.40)=12>10$, we can use the following approach:
\begin{align} 
& Z = \frac{X-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\\
\end{align}
\begin{align} 
& P(x-1=30) \Rightarrow P(x = 31)=\frac{31-18}{\sqrt{12}}=\frac{13}{2\sqrt{3}}=\frac{13\sqrt{3}}{6}=3.75\\ 
\end{align}

For $P(x>=29)$ I solved it like this:

\begin{align}
&P(29>=X)=1-P(X<=28)=1-\sum_{i=1}^{28}{P(x_i)}
\end{align}
Since $n$ is large and $p$ is small, we can use an approach which is very similar to $Poisson$ distribtution with $\lambda = np$:

\begin{align}
& P(X=k)=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!} * e^{-\lambda} \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
& P(29>=X)=1-\left(\frac{\lambda^1}{1!}*e^{-\lambda}+\frac{\lambda^2}{2!}*e^{-\lambda}+...+\frac{\lambda^{28}}{28!}*e^{-\lambda}\right) \\
& \ P(29>=X) = 1 - 0.98969 = 0.01031
\end{align}
Is this correct (I do not have access to the solutions for these exercises)?

> (B) Calculate the expected value $E(X)$ and the variance $V(X)$ to $X$ and $f(x)$. You can use the fact that $E(X^4)=1.19*10^5$

My solution:

\begin{align}
& E(X)=np=30*0.60=18 \\
& V(X)=np(1-p)=18(0.40)=7.2 \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
E(f(x))=E(X^2) = V(X)-\left(E(X)\right)^2 = 7.2-(18^2)=-316.8
\end{align}

But this didn't seem right to me, because of the negative result, so I tried using the hint($E(X^4)=1.19*10^5$):

\begin{align}
& E(X^4) = 1.19*10^5\Rightarrow E(X^2)=\sqrt{E(X^4)}=\sqrt{1.19*10^5}= 344.96
\end{align}

Is this correct? If not, how do I solve this correctly?

Comment: The approach you are using is based on the central limit theorem, which is a very good __approximation__ (not equality as you wrote) when $np$ and $n(1-p)$ is at least some threshold (you are using 10, some people 5, or 9, or 12, etc). Note however that $P(X = 30) = \dbinom{30}{30}(0.6)^30(0.4)^{30-30} = 0.6^30,$ no no approximation is required here. And $P(X \leq 29) = 1 - P(X = 30).$

Comment: "$P(x = 31)=\frac{31-18}{\sqrt{12}}$" This expression doesn´t make sense. Also $P(X=31)=0$, since $f(x)=0$ for $x=31$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand it now, or at least that first part.